# Preferred Python XML processor

Tags: python, xml

What is the preferred XML processor to use with Python?

Some choices are

- minidom
- PyXML
- ElementTree
- ...

EDIT: I will need to be able to read in documents and manipulate them. I also require pretty print functionality.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[lxml](http://lxml.de/) is where it's at.

Here's some example code:

```
import textwrap
from os.path import join

from lxml import etree

# string to Element
tree = etree.XML(textwrap.dedent('''
  <foo_tag>
    foo text
    <bar_tag some_attr='ok'>bar text</bar_tag>
  </foo_tag>
  '''))
print 'root text: ' , tree.text
print 'pretty_print: '
print etree.tostring(tree, pretty_print=True)
print 'last child: (%s) (%s)' % (tree[-1].tag, tree[-1].text)
print

# filename to ElementTree
tree = etree.parse('some_file.xhtml')

def recurse(root, depth):
  line = '  ' * depth + root.tag + ' {%s}' % ', '.join(root.attrib.keys())
  if root.text:
    line += ' <%s>' % root.text.strip()
  print line
  for child in root:
    recurse(child, depth + 1)
print 'recurse tree:'
recurse(tree.getroot(), 0)
print

print 'find title: ', tree.findtext('html/head/title')
print 'find title again: ', tree.find('html').find('head').find('title').text
```

Here's `some_file.xhtml` which you can use for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <metadata/>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title style="bold">Page Title</title>
      <span>Here's a <a href="google.com">link</a> to somewhere.</span>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#ffffff">Hello, World!</body>
  </html>
</root>
```

Comment: Actually this looks rather good. It gives you the simplicity of the ET interface with a whole load of other useful XML processing stuff like Xpath.

Comment: I concur lxml is probably the best available. It has the ElementTree interface but also allow to use XPath and co.

Answer (score 0):

I can vouch for ElementTree - it's not a particularly complete XML implementation. It's main strength is simplicity of use of the DOM tree objects. They behave like regular pythonic objects (sequences and dicts) even though their actual implementation is somewhat more complex than appearances might suggest. Of all the XML frameworks ET is the one that you can use to accomplish basic tasks quickly.

On the other hand if your XML is mostly quite conventional stuff it can do a good job of reading and formatting pretty much any document you throw at it.

Annoying limitations (which appeared not to have been fixed four months ago) is it's wonky support for XML namespaces, lack of Xpath.

In summary it's fine for basic uses. It will let you get up to speed very quickly. XML gurus will find it lacking.

Answer (score -1):

I'm a big fan of [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) ... I find its the easiest parser to use!

Comment: BeautifulSoup is not a general purpose XML propcessor. It's intended for brokenish HTML. It's probably best used for scraping web-pages.

Comment: Actually I use it exclusively for XML documents using the `BeautifulStoneSoup` parser. The wonderful thing is that it handles brokenish XML very well.

Answer (score -2):

If you are simply parsing a document and not manipulating it.  I would suggest using the SAX Parser for Python

http://docs.python.org/library/xml.sax.reader.html

Comment: SAX is a real pain in the a** to use. It's main strength is rapid parsing of XML and a low memory footprint. There's no need to maintain a DOM tree in memory. On the other hand, if you want to manipulate the XML that DOM tree is kind of helpful sometimes.

Comment: SAX is simple to use.  Simple API for XML.